Git Bash not showing on Select Default Profile options
I did some updates and deleted some (at first glance) useless files, opened VS Code and now I don't have the Git Bash option, and my terminal look weird, showing my 'main' directory and not 'git (branch-name)' as the prefix. I am quite new to programming so I appreciate any help.

VS Code Version: 1.88.1
OS Version: macOs Sonoma 14.4.1

enter image description here
I tried looking all over the internet but all I seemed to find was Windows solutions that I am not that good to try and implement on my Macbook

you might have deleted the .git folder within your project. That folder contains all the objects of your repository (commits, tags, trees, refs, index).
